# Something went wrong with the Activity lifecycle, not normal behavior by pressing home or task switch button

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, oncreate, ondestroy

Something is not OK in my code. Normally the activity lifecycle is
- at starting app: onCreate --> onStart --> onResume
- at closing app: onPause --> onStop --> onDestroy
- pressing the home button or the task switch button: onPause --> onStop
- coming back to the already opened app from another app: onStart --> onResume

But for some reason my app also calls onDestroy when I press the home button or the task switch button, and it calls onCreate, when I go back to the already opened app.

My app has 2 Activites:
- LoginActivity, which should appear first, if nobody is logged on, or if the logout button is pressed
- MainActivity to handle the main functions.

Please help me identify what causes this not normal behavior of lifecycle.

Thanks!

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

public Helper helper = new Helper(this);

public static final String SP_DATA = "SP_DATA";
public static final String FB_LOGIN_STATUS = "FB_LOGIN_STATUS";
public static final String FLRT = "FLRT";

public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

public FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(FLRT, "onCreate");
    helper.makeToast("onCreate");

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SP_DATA, MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean bAlreadyLoggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(FB_LOGIN_STATUS, false);

    if (bAlreadyLoggedIn) {
        Log.d(FLRT, "Already logged in");
    }
    else {
        Log.d(FLRT, "Not logged in");

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    showFragment(new FirstFragment(),"FirstFragment");

    Button btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            logout();

            showActivity(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

private void showActivity(Context context_fromActivity, Class<?> class_toActivty){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context_fromActivity, class_toActivty);
    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    startActivity(intent);

    MainActivity.this.finish();
}

private void logout() {
    Log.d(FLRT, "Logging out...");

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SP_DATA, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(FB_LOGIN_STATUS, false);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1 ){
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_first_layout:
            showFragment(new FirstFragment(), "FirstFragment");
            break;
        case R.id.nav_second_layout:
            showFragment(new SecondFragment(), "SecondFragment");
            break;
        case R.id.nav_third_layout:
            showFragment(new ThirdFragment(), "ThirdFragment");
            break;
        case R.id.nav_share:

            break;
        case R.id.nav_send:

            break;
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void showFragment(Fragment fragment, String sFragmentTAG) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(sFragmentTAG) != null) {
        Log.d(FLRT, "Fragment found, using existing one: " + sFragmentTAG);
        fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(sFragmentTAG);
    }

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, sFragmentTAG);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(FLRT, "onStart");
    helper.makeToast("onStart");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(FLRT, "onResume");
    helper.makeToast("onResume");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(FLRT, "onPause");
    helper.makeToast("onPause");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(FLRT, "onStop");
    helper.makeToast("onStop");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(FLRT, "onDestroy");
    helper.makeToast("onDestroy");
}
}
```

LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String SP_DATA = "SP_DATA";
public static final String FB_LOGIN_STATUS = "FB_LOGIN_STATUS";
public static final String FLRT = "FLRT";

public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

private Button btn_start;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);

    btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            login();

            showActivity(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);;
        }
    });
}

private void showActivity(Context context_fromActivity, Class<?> class_toActivty){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context_fromActivity, class_toActivty);
    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    startActivity(intent);

    LoginActivity.this.finish();
}

private void login() {
    Log.d(FLRT, "Logging in...");

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SP_DATA, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(FB_LOGIN_STATUS, true);
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

Comment: Some times if device has low memory then OS kills background apps. there may be memory issue in your device. try same code at another device

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Android Studio and with that the AVD Manager. And the same problem occours on my real device and in emulator too.

Comment: use device emulator is not trustworthy

Comment: But I also tried it on 2 different phones as well. It's something with/in the code, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing surprising here,

The behavior of `onDestroy()` method is

In some situations System simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method. OR System can directly destroy your app If its getting into low memory situations even your app is in [onStop()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop()) event, And another thing to notice is `onStop()` method also may not be called, in low memory situations.

See [`onDestroy()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) method in details.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Android Studio and with that the AVD Manager. And the same problem occours on my real device and in emulator too. And I also quickly wrote a simple app with logging the different lifecycles of an empty project, and there everything was working fine as expected. So it has nothing to do with low memory, it's something in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when you call MainActivity.this.finish(); or LoginActivity.this.finish(); the activity is distroyed. try not call finish() if you don't want destroy needed activity

Comment: Those parts are called directly with functions, and they have nothing to do with this problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: in the mainfest file ***android:noHistory="true"***
was set for both activities. Now the activity lifecycle is working fine.

However now from the Login screen I can simply can go back to the Main screen with pressing the Back button... and that's not ok. :)